# Amazon SES error while sending email MessageRejected

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

i am using php to send email with Amazon SES and using this github library

```
https://github.com/okamos/php-ses#getting-started
```

but when i send i get this error
my email and domain both are verified

```
     "MessageRejected" ["description"]=> string(134) "Indicates that the action failed, and the message could not be sent. Check the error stack for a description of what caused the error." }
```

when i checked for this error in aws i found this

```
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshoot-error-messages.html
```

here it says
If you call the Amazon SES API directly, the Query action will return an error. The error may be MessageRejected or one of the errors specified in the Common Errors topic of the Amazon Simple Email Service API Reference.

where we are missing ??

```
require 'autoload.php';

require 'src/ses.php';


$ses = new SimpleEmailService(
    'xxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    'us-east-1' 
);


$envelope = new SimpleEmailServiceEnvelope(
    'noreply@xxxxxxxx.com',
    'This is test email',
    'Hello how are you. this is test email'
);


$envelope->addTo('ffffff@hhhhh.com');

$requestId = $ses->sendEmail($envelope);

var_dump($requestId);
```

why we are getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice when you are sending mails via SES, specially if you are sending a lot of them, is use queues. For example, you can use AWS SQS to send mails via SES and avoid that problem.

Comment: so i now need aws SQS library ?? and that will have some cost

Comment: It has a little cost, but when you process a really high qty of messages monthly.

Comment: can you suggest any PHP library where i can use SQS with SES

Comment: Are you programming with a framework or native PHP